# Выделение активного пункта в NavigationView

Tags: android, xml

Как выделить активный пункт меню в `NavigationView`?
Пункты меню запускают `Fragment`, а сам `NavigationView` расположен в `activity`.
`NavigationView` инициализировал сам, не из стандартного шаблона от Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    navigation = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
    navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                    switch (id) {
                        case R.id.navigation_item:
                            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                                menuItem.setChecked(false);
                            } else {
                                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            }
                            break; //и т.д.
                }
    return false;
```

menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item"
            android:checked="false"/>
        ...
    </group> 
    .... 
</menu>
```

Comment: а как быть в том случае, если вместо фрагментов используются Activity? (NavigationView пересоздаётся с каждым запуском другого активити)

Answer (score 1):

Решил добавить ответ так же про Activity.

Если используете `Activity` вместо `Fragments` в `NavigationView`, то выделить выбранный пункт меню можно методом `setCheckedItem(idMenuItem);`
При этом, можно сделать отдельный родительский класс с инициализацией `NavigationView`, в сигнатуру которого из активити-класса можно добавить`id` пункта меню.

*Пример реализации:*

**Метод из родительского Activity:**

```
 protected void setupNavigationView(int idMenuItem) {

        initTogle();

        navigationView.setCheckedItem(idMenuItem);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.nav_menu_sales:
                        startSalesActivity();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_menu_tenders:
                        startTendersActivity();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_menu_shipments:
                        break;


                }









                return false;
            }
        });
```

**Вызов из нужного `Activity`:**

```
setupNavigationView(R.id.nav_menu_sales);
```

Разметка menu.xml такая же, как в ответе про Фрагменты.